# Do kills through Zin's 'Recite' ability grant experience?

Tags: dungeon-crawl-stone-soup

Zin's Recite ability occasionally smites enemies, and can for example petrify enemies into crumbling pillars of salt. They can also confuse enemies, a condition often lethal. Which of these outcomes grant experience for the reciting player and which don't?

Comment: I'd be surprised if either of these didn't grant experience. I'll be sure to test for that once I have enough time to play DCSS (by reciting with only a single enemy in sight and redirecting all of my experience to a 0-level skill). Just tell me first: have you figured it out in the year since you asking this question?

Comment: Also, there's a potential for a better question here: are there any ways of disposing enemies that do not grant experience?